# Группировка и суммирование строк по дням в MySQL - на php. Как?

Tags: mysql

Есть следующая задача. Строки в базе представлены примерно следующим образом:

```
_________________________________
| ID | sum |  time               |
|----|-----|---------------------|
| 1  | 32  | 2019-07-01 10:07:43 |
|----|-----|---------------------|
| 2  | 17  | 2019-07-01 09:23:21 |
|----|-----|---------------------|
| 3  | 41  | 2019-06-30 12:35:09 |
|----|-----|---------------------|
| 4  | 11  | 2019-06-30 11:55:31 |
|----|-----|---------------------|
| 5  | 22  | 2019-06-29 05:08:49 |
|----|-----|---------------------|
| 6  | 3   | 2019-06-29 04:24:42 |
 --------------------------------
```

Ну и таких строк несколько тысяч. Необходимо на php сделать вывод в таблицу и чтобы было отсортировано по дням. А значения 'sum' суммировались.
То есть в данном примере чтобы было нечто похожее:

```
2019-07-01 | 49
2019-06-30 | 52
2019-06-29 | 25
```

С суммой более менее понятно, это -
SELECT SUM(sum) FROM my_base WHERE time=***а вот тут уже не ясно***
Помогите кто сможет, спасибо! :) А если получится дать готовый код то будет совсем супер. ну или за подсказку буду благодарен.

Comment: вам не условие выборки нужно, а группировки `group by date(time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все что вам требуется сделать, это выбрать часть поля отвечающую за дату, просуммировать значения, и сгруппировать по этой самой дате

```
 SELECT date(`time`) as d
      , sum(`sum`) as s
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY date(`time`)
 ORDER BY d DESC
```